# Генератор строки

Tags: python, строки

Генератором строки назовём наименьший префикс, который нужно повторить (возможно, нецелое число раз) чтобы получить эту строку. Например, генератор строки "ababab" - это строка "ab", генератор строки "abcabca" - это строка "abc", генератором строки "abcd" является она сама.
По данной строке найдите её генератор.

**Входные данные**

Непустая строка, состоящая из строчных букв английского алфавита. Длина строки не превышает одного миллиона символов.

**Выходные данные**

Гениратор строки

**Тест:**
ababab
**Ответ:** ab 
**Тест:**
abcabca
**Ответ:** abc 
**Тест:**
abcd
**Ответ:** abcd

```
string = input()
gen_str = "" + string[0]
s = set(string[0], )
fiend_gen = False

for i in range(1,len(string)):
    if string[i] == string[0]:
        fiend_gen = True
        for j in range(i + 1, len(string)):
            if string[j] == string[0]:
                break
            elif not string[j] in s:
                gen_str += string[j]
                s.add(string[j])
if fiend_gen:
    print(gen_str)
else:
    print(string)
```

Comment: Ваш код где? Неужели вы решили что здесь за вас будут решать учебные задания?

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: @strawdog Извиняюсь, добавил код. Просто мне было стыдно его показывать

Comment: Ваша задача - это задача о поиске минимального периода строки, которою я почему-то сейчас не могу нагуглить в чистом виде. Учитывая, что последний периодичный кусок строки может быть нецелым, я могу вспомнить только один алгоритм, решающий эту задачу за O(N) (а учитывая ограничения в миллион символов, вам нужна именно линия) - это полный перебор всех префиксов строки и проверка с помощью полиномиальных хешей за O(1), что данный префикс действительно является периодом. Пусть мы рассматриваем префикс из P символов строки длины N, тогда проверка такая: `hash(0, n - p) == hash(p, n)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первый алгоритм более оптимизированный, в зависимости от конкретного содержимого тестов вполне может задачу с миллионом символов решить:

[Попробовать код онлайн!](https://tio.run/##bVLNboQgEL77FNOTkJomm95Me@0T9GY8sDhuUQIGsEn78naGdTfqFkkc@f5miNNP@vLudVk67CF6@40iyroAWspaXYGeg4Z3iJiESRgIlVX@kpnU@wCWWGAc/JpJBOUuKE4VWHTEhWc4MX@15MWGL6rrhJb3M9NnPkMS3nLN6RtVVnqXjJvxfsjhAydfU@2Bf/G@o9Y/w0Zyk40bGTU53Bqm98Fl7S82QwtPdBHN2D4SNnEfykb8l3AOqMbi4Ot8yspHzz0dyXXPCZjm4Kih2rY7oOABkQdsSnXmp6yAKs17LbtynWIKxiVRGlcTggT6OXF5/RdQymJZ/gA)

```
def solve(s):
    allc, curc = set(iter(s)), set()
    for l, c in zip(range(1, len(s) + 1), s):
        curc.add(c)
        if len(curc) < len(allc):
            continue
        for j in range(l):
            good = True
            for k in range(l + j, len(s), l):
                if s[j] != s[k]:
                    good = False
                    break
            if not good:
                break
        else:
            return s[:l]
            
for e in ['ababab', 'abcabca', 'abcd']:
    print('in:', e, 'out:', solve(e))
```

Вывод:

```
in: ababab out: ab
in: abcabca out: abc
in: abcd out: abcd
```

---

Второй алгоритм очень простой, но медленный для миллиона символов:

[Попробовать код онлайн!](https://tio.run/##VU/RCsIwDHzfV9xbW52M4VvBLxl7mC7TwGhH2wl@fW3cULzk4chdjmR5pYd355xHmhD9/CQdja1QMPkABjuEwd1JtzVmckXFEe1uEfAEHTvLPQ7Q@mthnIoNTQM2prPbvMflgvjbFQRKa3D4RPwJlRxAckCnhquUqlHYTXqno@q3tCWwS1qxs0WhIvo1Cd1eImOqnN8)

```
def solve(s):
    for i in range(1, len(s) + 1):
        if (s[:i] * ((len(s) + i - 1) // i))[:len(s)] == s:
            return s[:i]
            
for e in ['ababab', 'abcabca', 'abcd']:
    print('in:', e, 'out:', solve(e))
```

Вывод:

```
in: ababab out: ab
in: abcabca out: abc
in: abcd out: abcd
```

---

Тот же код что выше но в немного развёрнутом (упрощённом?) виде:

[Попробовать код онлайн!](https://tio.run/##VU9BDoMwDLvzCt9KBRe0WzVegjjACKMSalEJm/b6rhmIbU4OUWxHzvLiybtLjAONWP38oHzVJkPC6AMsrEPo3J3yqsRMLrEoUB0SQSjBqLE2xrYllDqJ52Rn@nhY43qYvz4Bo6gRzpUdwY3ZhS3qdPRfHoi34H4MgkxykuRsVNdLqRSj62/Sxziodr@0BOs4V9aZxFAi/cYy7p@T1lmMbw)

```
def solve(s):
    for i in range(1, len(s) + 1):
        r, t = s[:i], ''
        while len(t) < len(s):
            t += r
        if t[:len(s)] == s:
            return r
            
for e in ['ababab', 'abcabca', 'abcd']:
    print('in:', e, 'out:', solve(e))
```

Вывод:

```
in: ababab out: ab
in: abcabca out: abc
in: abcd out: abcd
```

---

Решил реализовать самый быстрый алгоритм, который я пока придумал, на основе [префикс-функции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). Там есть не оптимальная точка, но она гораздо реже случается, поэтому в среднем алгоритм будет гораздо быстрее чем `O(N^2)` сложность. Также под вопросом насколько верный алгоритм, надо проверять на тестах. Если не пройдёт время, то есть ещё место куда оптимизировать.

[Попробовать код олайн!](https://tio.run/##dVLbboMwDH3nK9yHCVipBNtbVfojCE2smDUoMyhAt309s0PGZeu4KPFxji/Hab/6a0PP41hiBa3BSn2@VANdgi48esAPQQoaiW1rtortLM7hEcgCVWNAgSIwBb1hkERAjilPzadblSk4QJLP6MdVaWTfGWIoqIQuUznsUl7rfOGu@PWWr6qJkt6n7FNIZkiy80moLWKwHwwxaC1Pmu4afcP/2uVMJGniJYcL4ftOjwjeFbVaCt3IF90XiKSVCOIIDslKKHRCLU3akAr2kDADZ7gT2AbhX60lQVsocLonng7CybEZQHiQeDvn5xhnTqe3wl0a6hUNuJFZ/@p@pUCXHVu9GUqhdSADmQYjRTJ/DwyICLUVAW9oOiyDSY1Oh2G4jf6jJq@B3Udc6TwN5xUJ5OawZIckh9MkyWT9GRUXunhzb@uxAXPPq6xMXGHmF6/y@hHw7iKf25Z2JSp8l6M1ivrAV3RkD7KzGXrZTlcKw9Abx28)

```
def prefix_func(s):
    n = len(s)
    pi = [0] * n
    for i in range(1, n):
        j = pi[i - 1]
        while j > 0 and s[i] != s[j]:
            j = pi[j - 1]
        if s[i] == s[j]:
            j += 1
        pi[i] = j
    return pi
    
def solve(s):
    n = len(s)
    if n == 0:
        return ''
    pi, minpl = prefix_func(s), n
    for i in range(n - 1, 0, -1):
        e = pi[i]
        pl = i + 1 - e
        sl = n - 1 - i
        if e == 0 or 2 * e < i + 1 or e % pl != 0 or sl >= pl:
            continue
        if sl == 0:
            return s[:pl]
        if all(s[j] == s[n - sl + j] for j in reversed(range(sl))):
            minpl = min(minpl, pl)
    if minpl == n and pi[-1] <= n - pi[-1]:
        return s[:n - pi[-1]]
    return s[:minpl]

for e in ['ababab', 'abcabca', 'abcd', 'anna']:
    print('in:', e, 'out:', solve(e))
```

Вывод:

```
in: ababab out: ab
in: abcabca out: abc
in: abcd out: abcd
```

Comment: К сожалению, первому алгоритму не хватает скорости.

Comment: @ВалерийТарасов Просто ради эксперимента попробуйте в первом моём коде заменить `for k in range(l + j, len(s), l):` на `for k in reversed(range(l + j, len(s), l)):`, это не изменит числа операций, но зато некоторые тесты вполне могут пройти лучше, т.к. уверен онлайн тестирующие серверы имеют тенденцию чаще запихивать повторы в префикс нежели в суффикс. Кстати вопрос, а на том сервере там много тестов? Не проходят прямо все или может 10% не проходит? Если не секрет то можно ссылку на задачку в оригинале? Наверняка это олимпиадный сервер типа HackerRank.

Comment: Не проходит только 14 тестов из 63 (Time Limit Exceeded). Ссылку на задачу в оригинале дать не получится, это учебный сервер университета. Манипуляция с переворотом не на один из тестов не повлияла.

Comment: @ВалерийТарасов Я сейчас подумаю и может придумаю какой то быстрый метод/алгоритм.

Comment: Буду очень благодарен!

Comment: @ВалерийТарасов Только что обновил ответ мой, добавил в самый конец новый алгоритм, который значительно быстрее должен работать. Но под вопросом его корректность. Я его только что придумал. Также есть место для оптимизации, если не пройдёт по скорости, то ещё буду думать как ускорить.

Comment: В некоторых тестах код даёт неверный результат. По моему, это из за за того, что генератор строки может повторяться нецелое число раз. Например, при тесте "anna", код возвращает ответ "anna", хотя правильным является "ann"

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123023/discussion-between-arty-and--).

Answer (score 3):

Вот как вариант... Немного не оптимально, т.к. ищет с конца и полностью проходит все длины строк от большей к меньшей.

```
def get_gen(txt):
    txt_len = len(txt)

    gen = txt
    while gen:
        test = (gen * (txt_len // len(gen) + 1))[:txt_len]
        if test == txt:
            result = gen
        gen = gen[:-1]

    print("Input    :", txt)
    return result

print("Generator:", get_gen("ababab"))
print("Generator:", get_gen("abcabca"))
print("Generator:", get_gen("abcd"))
print("Generator:", get_gen("aabbbccdaagdhhhgdtrreaabbbccdaagdhhhgdtrreaabbbccda"))
print("Generator:", get_gen("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"))
```

**UPD**. Хотя... Можно и с начала, тогда не придётся перебирать до конца (за исключением случая когда вся строка является генератором):

```
def get_gen(txt):
    txt_len = len(txt)

    gen = ""
    for ch in txt:
        gen += ch
        test = (gen * (txt_len // len(gen) + 1))[:txt_len]
        if test == txt:
            print("Input    :", txt)
            return gen

print("Generator:", get_gen("ababab"))
print("Generator:", get_gen("abcabca"))
print("Generator:", get_gen("abcd"))
print("Generator:", get_gen("aabbbccdaagdhhhgdtrreaabbbccdaagdhhhgdtrreaabbbccda"))
print("Generator:", get_gen("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"))
```

На выходе:

```
Input    : ababab
Generator: ab
Input    : abcabca
Generator: abc
Input    : abcd
Generator: abcd
Input    : aabbbccdaagdhhhgdtrreaabbbccdaagdhhhgdtrreaabbbccda
Generator: aabbbccdaagdhhhgdtrre
Input    : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Generator: x
```

Принцип в обоих случаях одинаков. В `gen` перебираются подстроки разных длин, затем из `gen` генерируется строка `test` такой же длины как и исходная `txt`. И если эти строки совпали, то строка-генератор найдена.